# Why is `max-width` better than `min-width` for responsive email design?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

One of the arguments against responsive **email** design is that media queries are often (still!) poorly supported in various email environments.  In these environments, the "desktop" version of the email is rendered instead of the "mobile" version.

The "trouble" environments tend to be the mobile ones - that is, most desktop environments seem to have good support for media queries.

Given this fact, it seems that the best approach to creating a responsive email would be to take a "mobile first" approach.  That is, to design the "default" email layout for the mobile environment.  The email could then be reformatted for desktop using media queries (i.e. by leveraging `min-width`).

The end result would be that even mobile environments that don't support media queries would render a mobile-appropriate email, while more full-featured desktop clients would render a desktop version.

The problem is, most responsive emails I see continue to use `max-width` instead of `min-width`, the opposite of what I would anticipate.

**For responsive email design, are there specific reasons why `max-width` is deliberately used instead of `min-width`?**

Comment: To the downvoter - I disagree that this is an opinion-based question.  I am seeking objective reasons why `max-width` is superior to `min-width`.  Is there a better way to phrase the question?

Comment: Update: I have further refined the question to entice more objective answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, max-width is used in designing an email with a desktop-sized design in mind. Min-width would be used to design mobile-first. It may be that the emails you are looking at were designed with desktop-sized screens in mind, or with an extensive number of media queries.

There are a few reasons why max-width might be used.

- For professional developers, they may have inherited old CSS from an already-existing site or template that they do not have the permission or ability to change.
- It may be that the email or website is more important for it to render nicely on a larger screen and include more information. This may be due to an audience who operate solely or mainly on desktops, or to a client who requests a very certain designer from a developer.
- Older email templates could have been designed in the age of a desktop-dominant field. It was only a few years back that smart phones and smaller screens became the norm, and older emails may not have adapted to this yet.

However, in my experience, if I can take a more opinionated answer for a moment, I prefer using max-width for my responsive email designs. My brain can comprehend using max-width as a cut-off better than min-width as a start point. So it may just be a personal preference for some people.

Comment: Sounds like I'm on the right track - for a brand new mobile-first design, max-width does not provide compelling advantages.

Comment: Sounds like it. Min-width is often better for a mobile site or design. For me, the most difficult part is changing my mindset. I've also found this link if it helps you a little bit more: http://www.the-haystack.com/2015/12/23/choosing-between-min-and-max-width/